# Android firebase connectivity showing error

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My android application is connected with firebase. It is working fine in another system. For me it showing the error.

```
GoogleApiAvailability: GMS core API Availability. ConnectionResult=0, tag=null
```

I tried several method but it showing this error. My code is shown below.

```
int result = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().showErrorNotification(this, result);
String msg = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorString(result);
```

It showing the error in third line.

Comment: Your result is int(number) not string. You are trying to use as String, so it going to null point.

Comment: Does the device / emulator you are using has google play services enabled ?
Do you have the gms-services implementation included in your build. gradle ?

Comment: @Younus I checked the functionality have no issue. It is int showErrorNotification method parameter also int. I am using physical device. I added the gms implementation in build.gradle

Comment: @Younus The value of result is getting 0.